Spivak's proof of the parallelogram law of forces
In Physics for Mathematicians, Spivak offers a "proof" of the parallelogram law for forces, i.e. the rule that forces combine according to the rule of standard vector addition. I say "proof" in quotes because this is an empirical fact, not a mathematical  one, so whether it can be "proven" depends on what axioms you're willing to assume about forces, which of course Spivak is aware of.
Spivak does not state a formal version of the "parallelogram law" explicitly, and he only sketches his proof. What I have here is my own formal statement, which I think is what Spivak meant. However, even following Spivak's hints I cannot prove this statement, and I am wondering if it's actually true.
Is this proposition true?

Proposition. Let $\oplus$ be a binary operation on (the set of vectors of) some vector space. Suppose that $\oplus$ is commutative, associative, and identical to the space's addition operator on one-dimensional subspaces, i.e. for any vector $u$ and scalars $a, b$, $au\oplus bu = au + bu$. Then $\oplus$ and $+$ are identical operations.

Again, this is my own statement based on my guess as to Spivak's exact axioms and assumptions by reading the text carefully, but not appearing explicitly in the book. Spivak's only hint as to a proof is this:

Consider the map
$$(a, b) = ae_1 + be_2 \rightarrow a e_1 \oplus b e_2$$
If $\oplus$ is associative, then this map will be linear. But it takes $e_1$ to $e_1$ and $e_2$ to $e_2$, so it must be the identity. Q.E.D.

This proof sketch appears verbatim on Wikipedia at time of writing, basically copy-pasted from the book, but I can't find any full proof or even exact theorem statement anywhere online. It's obviously not a complete proof though, and in fact, I'm unable to even show that this mapping is linear! If $\phi: \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ (Spivak restricts himself to two dimensions, but I imagine it works in any dimension if it works at all) is Spivak's map, then the best I can do is show that $\phi(u+v)=\phi(u)\oplus \phi(v)$, so it's a homomorphism between the two abelian groups, but not "linear" in the usual sense:
$$\begin{align}
\phi(u + v) &= (u+v)_x e_x \oplus (u + v)_y e_y \\\
&= (u_x e_x + v_x e_x) \oplus (u_y e_y + v_y e_y) \\\
&= (u_x e_x \oplus v_x e_x) \oplus (u_y e_y \oplus v_y e_y) \\\
&= (u_x e_x \oplus u_y e_y) \oplus (v_x e_x \oplus v_y e_y) \\\
&= \phi(u) \oplus \phi(v)
\end{align}$$

Did you copy the proposition correctly? It reads as "Suppose " without any implications.

@JonasHardt Fixed

I don't even see how to prove that $\phi$ is additive! Can you include your proof?

@QiaochuYuan done - is there a mistake?

I agree with you that something seems fishy here, and this doesn't seem true to me without more hypotheses. We can consider the following general idea: let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a completely arbitrary bijection, and set
$$v \oplus w = f^{-1}(f(v) + f(w)).$$
Then $\oplus$ is always commutative and associative (this is transport of structure). If we want $\oplus$ to agree with ordinary addition on $1$-dimensional subspaces this means
$$au \oplus bu = f^{-1}(f(au) + f(bu)) = au + bu$$
and this would be guaranteed if $f$ had the property of acting on every $1$-dimensional subspace by multiplication by some scalar. However, I don't see any reason that this scalar should be constant! So it seems to me that we can take $f$ to have the form
$$f(v) = g(\theta) v$$
where $g(\theta) : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is any non-constant function from angles to the positive reals and $v$ has polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ (and we can set $g = 0$ if $v = 0$) such that $g(\theta) = g \left( \theta + \pi \right)$; for example we can take $g(\theta) = \sin 2 \theta + 2$.
In terms of the function $\phi$, I agree with you that we have $\phi(u + v) = \phi(u) \oplus \phi(v)$, but it doesn't seem to me that we can guarantee any reasonable interaction between $\oplus$ and scalar multiplication, nor can we guarantee that, for example, $\phi(e_1 + e_2) = e_1 + e_2$, and both of these are false for $\oplus$ as constructed above.

So I suppose Spivak had something else in mind. Shame we can't ask him anymore. In the same section he mentions an assumption of rotational symmetry, i.e. any orthogonal map $T$ is an automorphism for $\oplus$. I think that undoes your counterexample (find a flip to exchange an arbitrary pair of vectors to show that $g(\theta)$ must be constant), and I think the result is true with that assumption. However, if we have to use some argument exploiting symmetry then I don't think I can really agree with him that the result is just a "trivial" consequence of associativity, as he writes.

@Jack: rotational symmetry seems likely to work although I still don't see a nice argument off the top of my head. And I agree if that's what he says re: associativity.
